# How to handle routes on page refresh in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have parent routes like this

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'posts', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'posts', component: PostsComponent, children: PostRoutes }
];
```

Now the children routes are like this

```
export const PostRoutes = [
  { path: '', component: PostsListComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: PostDetailComponent }
]
```

Now when I navigate to `localhost:4200` or `localhost:4200/posts` it select the first child route and render `PostsListComponent`, which lists all the posts. when i click on single post then it takes me to the URL `localhost:4200/posts/1` and render `PostListComponent` which list one single post and it details.

Now the problem is when i reload the page with this this route `localhost:4200/posts/1`, It takes me to the base URL `localhost:4200` and gives me error that cannot read property `comments` of undefined, since posts has many comments.

The problem is since on reloading the page, `posts array` is `null`, so it is not able to select a post with the postId from the URL. so it is giving me above error.

So how to manage that on reloading the page, first all posts must be loaded.

Below is my `posts.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Below is my `posts-list.component.html`

```
 <div [routerLink]="['/posts', post.id]" *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
   <h3>{{post.description}}</h3>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a guard for the routes that depend on data to be loaded, that only completes after the data is available.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards for documentation.